# "the" before plural generic noun

Tags: definite-articles

I have found the following sentence in "The Catcher in the Rye".

> If there's one thing I hate, it's the movies.

As far as I know one should use zero article before plural generics.
Why does the hero use "the" before "movies"? Is this just a mistake?

Are there cases when one can use "the" before a plural generic?

Comment: *the movies* is **not** plural. http://www.macmillandictionary.com/us/dictionary/american/the-movies

Comment: @Kris Maybe this question is indeed off-topic, but I need to notice that the article [_movie_](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/us/dictionary/american/movie) doesn't link to [_the movies_](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/us/dictionary/american/the-movies) (this holds also for some of the other online dictionaries). Thus it would be hard for me to find an answer by myself without already knowing that this is an idiom. Anyway, thank you for the link!

Comment: "the movies: idiomatic noun. Americans use "the movies" for the word "cinema", as a place where they see a film" http://onlinetutorforenglish.com/daily-conversations/going-to-the-movies.php

Answer (score 1):

In most cases, you'd be right: the definite article indicates that the following noun has been introduced previously or is in some other way within the semantic ‘scope’ of the discourse.

This is a somewhat special case, though, since *the movies* (apart from just being the definite plural of ‘movie’ as in *the movies I rented last week are overdue*) has a separate and specific meaning: *cinema(s)*.

If you go *to the movies*, you are specifically not watching a movie at home, but in a movie theatre/cinema. In this sense, *the movies* is an originally synecdochical reference to the movies watched there, but it serves now as a simple reference to cinemas—often with singular agreement:

> The movies is my favourite thing in the world!

So here, the character could just as well have said:

> If there's one thing I hate, it's cinemas.

(Note the lack of an article when using a different word.)

It just happens that, for whatever reason, *the movies* was lexicalised in the definite form alone. “If there's one thing I hate, it's movies” is of course also a perfectly correct sentence, but it means something slightly different.

Comment: Can you substantiate your claim that the movies is synecdochical? While I agree it *could* be, it would certainly differ from my and my parents' experience. They and I certainly referred to "the movies" as distinct from the cinema, as in "I went to the open-air movies" (quoting from late 1930's).

Comment: It is synecdochical in the sense that it refers to a place, named after the event that takes place there. It is not a true, classical synecdoche, since it is not a literal part of the whole that is referenced; but I don't know of any more specific word for this type of metonymy. Whether _cinema_, _the movies_, and _movie theatre_ are exact synonyms is beyond the answer I gave—I was merely emphasising that _the movies_ here refers to more than simply the recorded images on strips of film: it is a place, and even a culture.

Comment: Ok. I understand your point, but disagree. It's not the way *the movies* came about, from my knowledge, in AE or BE. Always willing to recant in the face of actual evidence, though :-)

Answer (score 1):

I think the term *the movies* has become idiomatic, and in that sense, it is generic of movies in general; but it may be a mistake to call this a universal rule. Generally speaking, the generic plural comes anarthrous (no article), and the generic singular comes indefinite (with the indefinite article *a),* although in rare instances the definite generic singular (with the definite article *the),* is also used.

Comment: You think? http://www.macmillandictionary.com/us/dictionary/american/the-movies

Comment: @Kris I fail to see how this contradicts anything I said in my answer.

Comment: Why does it *have* to contradict? When there's an authentic source of information, you don't have to still "think" but cite the source instead. Opinions are not answers. HTH.

Answer (score -2):

It is not a mistake; it is dialog.  Holden Caulfield was not written to sound like a perfect adolescent with perfect grammar, not the character's style.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with this quote, neither in style nor in grammar.